# Using MongoDB Spark Connector to filter based on timestamp

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, apache-spark-sql, mongodb-hadoop

I am using [Spark MongoDB connector](https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/master/scala/read-from-mongodb/) to fetch data from mongodb..However I am not able to get how I can query on Mongo using Spark using aggregation pipeline(rdd.withPipeline).Following is my code where I want to fetch records based on timestamp & store in dataframe :

```
 val appData=MongoSpark.load(spark.sparkContext,readConfig)
val df=appData.withPipeline(Seq(Document.parse("{ $match: { createdAt : { $gt : 2017-01-01 00:00:00 } } }"))).toDF()
```

Is this a correct way to query on mongodb using spark for timestamp value?

Comment: I know nothing of it but I'm presuming it uses the [Extended JSON Syntax](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/) for such strings and therefore should possibly be `("{ $match: { createdAt : { $gt : { $date: ' 2017-01-01T00:00:00.000' }  } } }")` using the [`$date`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/#date) type as shown.

Comment: Can you please paste a sample query for this ?

Comment: ?????? What do you think I did if not "paste a sample"??????

Answer (score 0):

As the comment mentioned, you could utilise the [Extended JSON](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/) format for the date filter.

```
val appDataRDD  = MongoSpark.load(sc)
val filteredRDD = appDataRDD.withPipeline(Seq(Document.parse("{$match:{timestamp:{$gt:{$date:'2017-01-01T00:00:00.000'}}}}")))
filteredRDD.foreach(println)
```

See also [MongoDB Spark Connector: Filters and Aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/master/scala/aggregation/) to see an alternative filter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
val pipeline = "{'$match': {'CreationDate':{$gt: {$date:'2020-08-26T00:00:00.000Z'}}}}"

val sourceDF = spark.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").option("uri", "mongodb://administrator:password@10.XXXXX:27017/?authSource=admin").option("database","_poc").option("collection", "activity").option("pipeline", pipeline).load()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

try this(but it has limitation like mongo date and ISODate can only take TZ format timestamp only.

```
option("pipeline", s"""[{ $$match: { "updatedAt" : { $$gte : new ISODate("2022-11-29T15:26:21.556Z") } } }]""").mongo[DeltaComments]
```